# Bulk select, edit multiple sections, and remove duplicate/unnecessary tags in a file

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++

I have multiple sections in my XML template (270) that are not properly styled, like this for example:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>LONDON, United Kingdom <strong><strong><b><strong>
—</strong></b></strong></strong></strong>

<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>NEW YORK, United States <strong>— </strong>

<p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>SHEUNG WAN, Hong Kong — </strong>
```

The proper style should be:

```
 <p style="text-align: justify;"><strong>SHEUNG WAN, Hong Kong</strong> —
```

Basically it should display the location in bold before the '—' and text comes after.

Comment: Please show what did you attempt so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, you can

1. using search/replace, remove all `<strong>`, `</strong>`, `</b>`, `</b>` so you get text data as consistent plain text
2. return necessary `<strong>` and `</strong>` into desired position by search/replace